# Compilation error running C code using GSL on Windows to be called through R

Tags: c, r, gsl

I need to call the following C code through R using GSL (GNU lib). The problem I'm having is in the compilation of the C code. 
Here is the program mean.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <R.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_statistics.h>

void gsl(double *x, int *n)
{
    double mean = gsl_stats_mean(x, 1, n);
    Rprintf("mean = %f\n", mean);
}
```

Command> `R CMD SHLIB mean.c`

Output>

```
cygwin warning:
    MS-DOS style path detected: C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/etc/i386/Makeconf
    Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/c/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/etc/i386/Makeconf
    CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
    Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
       http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
gcc -m32 -shared -s -static-libgcc -o mean.dll tmp.def mean.o ipconfig -Ld:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/lib/i386 -Ld:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/lib -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/bin/i386 -lR
mean.o:mean.c:<.text+0x1b>: undefined references to 'gsl_stats_mean'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

In the command Prompt I am giving the following command also:

```
>gcc mean.c -Wall -I"C:/Program Files/GnuWin32/include/gsl" -L"C:/Program Files/GnuWin32/lib" -lgslcblas -lgsl -lm -o mean
```

I have tried all the other permutations of putting mean.c in between and at the end but the compilation is terminated always, giving the message "ld returned 1 exit status". Sometimes giving the message 'R.h' - No such file or directory.

I have also edited the PATH and included GnuWin32 folder and its constituents. 
Am I proceeding in the right direction?
Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks!

--Ankit

Comment: Use `R CMD SHLIB mean.c` to compile a shared library with appropriate headers available; see section 5.5 of 'Writing R Extensions'. Hopefully this is just an example, and you have no intention of using gsl's mean rather than R's.

Comment: Actually I am working on a big code in R(involves multivariate normal density functions etc.) and to make it run in lesser time(as it involves many loops), I am using C. I thought of making a simple program first using GSL to check whether I can compile it or not. 
I tried the R CMD SHLIB mean.c command at the start but it is not creating any .dll file, only the .o file is being created. What am I missing_

Comment: Please update your question to include the complete output of `R CMD SHLIB mean.c`.

Comment: This means that it compiles but does not link -- it has found the relevant header files, but cannot find the dll where gsl_stats_mean is defined. Define this with something like `SHLIB_LDFLAGS = -L$(LIB_GSL)$(R_ARCH)/lib -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm`, 
`SHLIB_CXXLDFLAGS += -I$(LIB_GSL)$(R_ARCH)/include`; see R CMD config for available variables. Likely you'll write a Makefile.win for these instructions.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I'm still getting the same error. Could you please specify a command here which I can use?
I have set/defined the variables as you discussed above, the result is No such file or directory.

Comment: Sorry, my commands were relevant on linux. From `R CMD SHLIB --help` it seems that the linker flags (like those above; you'll need to identify the correct libraries / paths) can be specified on the command line after test.c, something like `R CMD SHLIB test.c -Lc:/path/to/gsl/libs -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm`. I'm mostly shooting in the dark here so someone else will need to step in with a more complete solution.

Comment: I tried this. Not working. Anyway thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

The [RcppGSL package](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.gsl.html) has working examples in the [included and fully-working package](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rcppgsl/tree/master/inst/examples/RcppGSLExample) as well as in a simpler spline example.  In short, you need to supply a bit more to `make` and the compiler.

But as Martin Morgan noted in the comment, you also haven't exactly motivated why you would want to call the mean function from the GSL from R...

Comment: I first thought of using Rcpp only but was not able to install it in my computer. Also what do you mean by "to supply a bit more to 'make' and the compiler"?